# Fonts & If Thens

Tags: microsoft-excel, fonts

I have an Excel doc that I have built with an `if then` argument that says 'if a selected field is equal to another, then the impacted field will be equal to another'.

`=IF(I2=Q5,S5,IF(I2=Q2,S2,IF(I2=Q3,S3,IF(I2=Q4,S4,IF(I2="","",IF(I2=Q6,S6, IF(I2=Q7,S7,IF(I2=Q8,S8,IF(I2=Q9,S9,IF(I2=Q10,S10,IF(I2=Q11,S11,IF(I2=Q12,S12,IF(I2=Q13,S13,IF(I2=Q14,S14,IF(I2=Q15,S15)))))))))))))))`

I'm sure that there's a better way to do this, but this is as far as my self- taught Excel skills go.  That's not my issue though.  In my "S" fields, there are some font differences (color, bold).  How can I get those to come over so that when I get my final product they are as I entered them?

Example:

Upon review, enrollment for **insert enrollee or enrollees** was located. We have processed the records and cofirmed that the premium amount is **insert premium amount**.

Comment: you can set a table array (2 columns), (Q column should be before S) R and S (R has the value of Q) and use vlookup to find I and grab S

Answer (score 0):

If the font differences can be described by a formula, and are limited to font color and bold, Conditional Formatting would be an option. It cannot, however, change the font or font size. For Excel 2010, that would be on the Home tab of the ribbon. You could use the New Rule option and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format." You can use something like `=I2=S5` and then select some formatting. Then apply it to whatever range your data is in

As far as the formula, I'd probably go with `index` and `match`. 
Something like `=INDEX(S1:S21,MATCH(I2,Q1:Q21,0))` would look at the value in `I2` and find a match in `Q1:Q21` and then display whatever is in the same row as the matched value but from the S column.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I think maybe I didn't explain myself correctly (or I am not xcel savvy enough to get what you're telling me, which is totally possible).  I only want to change the font on a few words in the field.  Basically, I am doing a mail merge and I'd like the "insert here" fields to stand out so that it is easier to see on the letters.

Comment: So, with conditional formatting you could make all the text in a cell bold. There is not a way, that I am aware of, to make only specific words in the cell bold, without using VBA and writing a macro. From your formula above, is there specific cell that needs to have bold text?

Comment: No there is not :(. Only specific words within.  This is not the first time that I've wished I knew more about Excel.